# Put Array in to Table Column

Tags: pytables

I'm trying to store information in a pytables subclass. I have my class Record and subclass Data. Data will have many rows for every row of Record. I don't want to use a loop with row.append() because it seems like it would be horribly slow. Can I just create an array and drop it in Data.v column?  How?

```
import tables as tbs
import numpy as np

class Record(tbs.IsDescription):
    filename  = tbs.StringCol(255)
    timestamp = tbs.Time32Col()
    class Data(tbs.IsDescription):
        v = tbs.Int32Col(dflt=None)

...
row = table.row
for each in importdata:
    row['filename'] = each['filename']
    row['timestamp'] = each['timestamp']

    # ???? I want to do something like this
    row.Data = tbs.Array('v', each['v'], shape=np.shape(each['v']))
    row.append()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, When I read about nested tables I was think about relational data in a one-to-many situation.  This isn't possible with nested tables.  Instead I just created a separate table and stored row references using

```
tables.nrows
```

to get the current row of my Data table. This works for me because for every entry in Record I can calculate the number of rows that will be stored in Data. I just need to know the starting row. I'm not going to modify/insert/remove any rows in the future so my reference doesn't change.  Anyone considering this technique should understand the significant limitations it brings.

Answer (score 0):

Nested columns use the '/' separator in the column key.  So I think that you simply need to change the line:

```
row.Data = tbs.Array('v', each['v'], shape=np.shape(each['v']))
```

to the following:

```
row['Data/v'] = each['v']
```

Comment: I tried that but got: TypeError: invalid type (<type 'list'>) for column ``Data/v`` ... Don't I need to put it in an array?

Comment: Oh yeah.  You might need to do row['Data/v'] = np.array(each['v'])